# how to send client id of a row of gridview to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a `GridView` with some information in it. When I click on one of the rows, I want to send its `ClientId` to JavaScript.

C# code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ChangeRowColor('" + e.Row.ClientID + "')");
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeRowColor(row) {
        alert(row);
</script>
```

but the problem is that when I click on a row it returns `"gridview1"`, and that isn't the row's ID.
How can I send a `GridView` row ID to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword. In the context of your function, `this` will refer to the row.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ChangeRowColor(this)");
```

And then access the id by using the id attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeRowColor(row)
        alert(row.id);
</script>
```

**Additional Information**

The `javascript:` prefix is unnecessary in this context.

Comment: @mehdi, Can you show the markup that is rendered for the row?

Comment: @mehdi, Right click on the page, and "view source". Find the row you clicked on and copy the markup.

Comment: i saw that.all of row's id is Gridview1!

Comment: @mehdi, So that code works - sounds like you may have another issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the row itself (a DOM element) by passing `this`:

```
onclick="changeColor(this);"
```